# flash.delete(:notice) not working in Rails 3.1 RC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

A few months ago, I followed this [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery). Everything worked in Rails 3.0.X, but in Rails 3.1 RC, I get this error:

```
undefined method `gsub' for #<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x00000108338f20>
```

Has anything changed in Rails 3.1 RC with the flash object? It seems the problem is with this line:

```
<%= escape_javascript(flash.delete(:notice)) %>
```

Full trace:

```
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/helpers/javascript_helper.rb:21:in `escape_javascript'
app/views/likes/create.js.erb:4:in `_app_views_likes_create_js_erb___2491329848991146022_2217047840'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:144:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:57:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:142:in `render'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:33:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:55:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:55:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:33:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:39:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:38:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:12:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:22:in `wrap_formats'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:9:in `render'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:258:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:114:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:30:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:43:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:99:in `render'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
/Users/Chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:309:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:78:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.1.0.rc1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:452:in `_run__308249102964749222__process_action__3107984421769475816__callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:55:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:55:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:202:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.1.0.rc1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.1) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.8.1) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.1) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:82:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.8.1) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.1) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:531:in `call'
/Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/bundler/gems/omniauth-795d965b8961/oa-core/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:44:in `call!'
/Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@railspre/bundler/gems/omniauth-795d965b8961/oa-core/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:30:in `call'
warden (1.0.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.0.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.0.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.3.0) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.3.0) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:243:in `call'
rack (1.3.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
rack (1.3.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:321:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.0.rc1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:54:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68:in `call'
rack (1.3.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:102:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.1.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.3.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.3.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.1.0.rc1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.3.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.1.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/content_length.rb:16:in `call'
railties (3.1.0.rc1) lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `call'
railties (3.1.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.3.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/Chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/Users/Chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/Chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: What is the output of `flash.delete(:notice).class.name` ? Hopefully it is `String` and not `FlashHash`? Maybe somehow the `flash` got embedded into `flash[:notice]` itself?

Comment: Hi Zabba, good observation. flash.delete(:notice).class.name returns ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash. Is this normal?

Comment: "puts flash[:notice]" returns the actual flash message in rails console / terminal. So I don't know why this is not working accordingly

Comment: Inspect the returned `FlashHash` -- does it contain the message you are looking for or is it empty? `puts flash[:notice]` is working as expected in 3.1 RC ?

Comment: Zabba, yea the message is there. "puts flash[:notice]" shows the expected message. Whats not working is flash.delete(:notice).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `FlashHash` has changed between 3.0.x and 3.1.x.

[In Rails 3.0.x, `FlashHash` was derived from `Hash`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb#L69). Thus when you called `delete`, it was `Hash`'s `delete` called - which deletes the
specified key and returns the key's value.

[In Rails 3.1, `FlashHash` is not derived from `Hash`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb#L73) - it is including `Enumerable`. And the `FlashHash#delete` is returning `self` i.e. `FlashHash`.
Thus, your error.

Why the Rails team needed to change this, is beyond me.

I guess you need a workaround that works in both 3.0.x and 3.1:

```
escape_javascript(flash[:notice])
flash[:notice] = nil
```

Comment: Awesome references! From reading those links, I gathered in 3.1 flash.discard(:notice) seems to work like the same behavior for flash.delete(:notice) in Rails 3.0.X.

Comment: I think they have changed this because of the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 16):

Use `flash.discard(:notice)`

*(Courtesy Christian, I added this solution for better visibility)*

Answer (score 1):

In rails 3, it's more towards a using the :notice option in redirect_to for setting the notice. It's possible some of the methods of flash were deprecated in 3.0.#, and are now removed. I'm not sure what the best solution is there, perhaps to just set it to nil.

```
flash[:notice] = nil

# in your view:
<% if notice %>
  <%= notice %>
<% end %>
```

If you're trying to setup jQuery, it's now default in 3.1.

Comment: I'm not trying to set the flash on redirect. The flash message has already been set. The problem is, it's not displaying the flash message in create.js.erb

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding. But i agree with the other comment thread. If you just want to see the notice, use flash[:notice] in your view.