# Rails - `flash.discard` vs `flash.delete`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash-message

As title, I wonder what's the difference between Rails `flash.discard` and `flash.delete`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[@SteveTurczyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2516474/steveturczyn) is right.

However, `flash.delete` is only possible to do in versions of rails previous to 3.1.

As of 3.1, `flash.delete` doesn't work anymore, an alternative might be `flash.clear` (check out [flash.delete(:notice) not working in Rails 3.1 RC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170063/flash-deletenotice-not-working-in-rails-3-1-rc)).

You might also want to check: https://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash/discard

Answer (score 4):

`flash.delete` is immediate.  `flash.discard` will remove the flash at the end of the current action.

So using `flash.discard` you can still examine the flash contents in the current action.